# Laravel 5.7. Как сделать вывод валидации для отдельной формы?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

Имеется такого вида Form Request:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'login' => 'required|max:255|alpha_dash',
            'pass' => 'required|min:6|max:255|same:pass_conf',
            'pass_conf' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'login.required' => 'Поле ввода не должно быть пустым или иметь пробелы',
            'login.max' => 'Логин не может содержать больше 255 символов',
            'login.alpha_dash' => 'Поле можно содержать только алфавитные символы, цифры, знаки подчёркивания "_" и дефисы "-"',
            'pass.required' => 'Поле ввода не должно быть пустым или иметь пробелы',
            'pass.min' => 'Пароль должен содержать не менее 6 символов',
            'pass.max' => 'Пароль не может содержать больше 255 символов',
            'pass.same' => 'Пароли не совпадают!',
            'pass_conf.required' => 'Поле ввода не должно быть пустым или иметь пробелы',
        ];
    }
```

Вот так организованы формы и вывод ошибок из Form Request:

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('setusername') }}" >
   {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="login" class="control-label">Изменить текущий логин</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-sm-2 mb-2" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Введите новый логин">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Изменить</button>
     </div>



    @if ($errors->any())  {{-- Вывод сообщений о некорректном вводе --}}
         <div class="alert alert-danger inline-block mt-1">
            <ul>
               @foreach ($errors->get('login') as $message)
                  <li>{{ $message }}</li>
                @endforeach
              </ul>
            </div>
    @endif         
</form>
```

Методы контроллера:

```
public function setusername(ProfileValidationRequest $request)
{
        $username = $request->login;

        Auth::user()->name = $username;
        Auth::user()->save();
        return redirect('/profile');
}

public function setpassword(ProfileValidationRequest $request)
{
    $password = Hash::make($request->pass);

    Auth::user()->password = $password;
    Auth::user()->save();
    return redirect('/profile', $password);
}
```

Маршруты:

```
Route::post('profile.setusername', 'ProfileController@setusername')->name('setusername');
Route::post('profile.setpass', 'ProfileController@setpassword')->name('setpass');
```

Проблема в том, что с таким условием при отправке любой формы на всех остальных также появляются сообщения об ошибках. В общем нужна помощь с оформлением условия так, что бы сообщения об ошибках появлялись только на отправленной форме.

p.s Как оказалось ещё и валидация не проходит, выдавая пустой div alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы реализовать вывод ошибок только для определенной формы, нужно сделать следующее:

в вашем ProfileValidationRequest добавьте такую переменную класса:

```
protected $errorBag = 'login';
```

После этого ошибки только по этой форме в шаблонах будут доступны в переменной

```
$errors->login
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, никак не пойму куда нужно добавить
`protected $errorBag = 'login';` в Form Request, в какой-то из методов или просто в класс валидатора?

Comment: в ProfileValidationRequest. переменные класса добавляются просто в класс)